# How to estimate density of Polygon intersections in R?

Tags: r, arcgis, r-sf

I have many polygons that represent search areas of different people. By intersecting all that areas I want to get density map - 1 person searched in this area, two in that area and so on.

My trouble is that I have >5k geoJSON polygons and I need to intersect all of them. Is there a way to do it R's sf package or (less preferably) in ArcGIS?

Comment: I assume this is possible. A small sample of data would help. Please make your question reproducible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please share a small reproducible example. If you need help on how to do that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: See the last plot [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html). You just need to have a `sf` polygon object. If those >5k polygons are in one `geoJSON` file, then it should be as easy as `mysf = sf::st_read("/path/to/my_polygons.geojson")`.

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010155/intersection-of-polygons-in-r-using-sf